# generalizing module import in python

Tags: python

I am actually a little confused about making module import generalize. What I got here is a class `shape`. What I want to do is  want to import corresponding file as a module based on some condition. What i'm trying to do is:

In `Shape.py`

```
class shape:
    def __init__(self, shape_id):
        if shape_id == '001':
            from shapes import triangle as imported_shape
        else:
            from shapes import square as imported_shape
```

In `main.py`:

```
from Shape import shape

sqaure = shape('002')
...
```

The project structure is:

```
Project
    |
      Shape.py
      main.py
      shapes
          |
            triangle.py
            square.py
```

but that does not seems to work as the import is made void after the `__init__` function. Is there any way i can make this type of importing more generalized?

Comment: What is your project structure ?

Comment: imports stay in the scope of functions as any objects

Comment: @YaroslavSurzhikov updated question with project structure

Comment: @PRMoureu That seems to work, but what i want is to import the module when initializing an object so that I could pass on the `id` while initialization.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't reproduce your bug.

As test I've included similar method to both square and triangle modules, which prints square or triangle respectively, something like that:

```
def a():
    print('square')
```

I called it in `__init__` of **shape** class and recieved expected output.

```
class shape:
    def __init__(self, shape_id):
        if shape_id == '001':
            from shapes import triangle as imported_shape
        else:
            from shapes import square as imported_shape

        imported_shape.a()
```

But if you want to use imported module somewhere elsewhere of `__init__` - you should assing `imported_shape` to **self**:

```
class shape:
    def __init__(self, shape_id):
        if shape_id == '001':
            from shapes import triangle as imported_shape
        else:
            from shapes import square as imported_shape

        self.imported_shape = imported_shape
```

And after that - you can access your module in other methods of **shape** class:

```
def test(self):
    self.imported_shape.a()
```

According to your needs and python code standarts - it would be better to import shapes on top of your module and in `__init__` do something like:

```
import shapes

class shape:
    def __init__(self, shape_id):
        if shape_id == '001':
            self.imported_shape = shapes.triangle
        else:
            self.imported_shape = shapes.square
```

OOP example:

Asuming that square and triangle have same-named classes:

```
from shapes.square import square
from shapes.triangle import triangle


class shape(square, triangle):
    def __init__(self, shape_id):
        if shape_id == '001':
            super(triangle, self).__init__()
        else:
            super(square, self).__init__()
```

Comment: It works, but my doubt is, is it a good approach to assign an import to a class variable?

Comment: @MrPyCharm, well, thats not ideal, yeah. Better approach would be to inherit classes *triangle* and *square* in class *shape* and on `__init__` call `super(shapes.triangle, self).__init__()` or `super(shapes.square, self).__init__()` according to id passed as param